# How do I adjust where the calendar appears for the datePicker in the Grails UI plugin without the position changing when the page is resized?

Tags: grails, datepicker, yui, grails-plugin

I wanted to change where the calendar appeared for the datePicker portion of the Grails UI plugin.  After a bit of digging, I found it in the InputTagLib.groovy file:

```
                    out << """
            YAHOO.util.Event.on("${showButtonId}", "click", function() {
                var buttonRegion = YAHOO.util.Dom.getRegion('${showButtonId}');
                var buttonHeight = buttonRegion.bottom - buttonRegion.top;
                var buttonWidth = buttonRegion.right - buttonRegion.left;
                var xy = YAHOO.util.Dom.getXY('${showButtonId}');
                var newXY = [xy[0] + buttonWidth, xy[1] + buttonHeight];
                YAHOO.util.Dom.setXY('${id}_calContainer_c', newXY);
                GRAILSUI.${jsid}Panel.show();
                if (YAHOO.env.ua.opera && document.documentElement) {
                    // Opera needs to force a repaint
                    document.documentElement.className += "";
                }
            });"""
```

The position is set on this line:

```
                    YAHOO.util.Dom.setXY('${id}_calContainer_c', newXY);
```

The YAHOO.util.Dom.setXY() method takes two arguments.

> The first argument of the setXY method is either the ID of an HTMLElement, or an actual HTMLElement object. The second argument is an array containing two values: [x, y] where x is the distance from the left edge of the document, and y is the distance from the top edge of the document.

Source: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/dom/setxy.html

So I can easily adjust where the calendar appears by changing the values in the newXY variable that is passed to the setXY method and it works fine.

However, if I resize the page, the calendar positions its top left corner directly under the showButton's bottom left corner.  What is it that makes the repositioning happen when the page is resized and how can I resolve it?

**EDIT :** A little more info:

- This happens in the most recent versions of IE, Firefox, and Chrome
- If I resize the page and then click the button to show the calendar, the calendar shows in the expected place but it will reposition if I resize the page again once the calendar is open